# trigger a command on a remote path from /tmp

Tags: bash, shell

I am using below line to get the size of individual directories under a specific path `/apps/newone` .

```
du -sh *
```

as there are write issue , I cannot have a script under that path. I though of trying from `/tmp`. But if I try it will show the files under `/tmp`, which is expected.
Is there a way I can set the remote path and make the script to run on that path by being on `/tmp`?

for now, I am doing this, but when I do `cd -` it is showing the `/tmp` path .

```
cd /apps/newone ; du -sh * | sort -hr ; cd -
12G     lithium
11G     sodium
160M    soking
/tmp
```

can someone be able to help me with a solution, Thank you!

edit: tried something

```
cd /apps/newone ; du -sh * | sort -hr ; cd - >> /dev/null 2>&1
12G     lithium
11G     sodium
160M    soking
```

seems like I am getting what I need, but is this the effective way?

Comment: is there a reason why you don't run `du -sh /apps/newone` ? sure, this will add `/apps/newone` to each line of output but that's easy to **a)** ignore or **b)** remove

Comment: That is true, I have tried the mentioned way . As you said thee is prefix, can you help me on how I can ignore/remove it from output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting stdout from `cd -` to `/dev/null` is certainly the easy way to eliminate the trailing `/tmp`, eg:

```
cd /apps/newone ; du -sh * | sort -hr ; cd - >/dev/null
```

---

Expanding on my previous comment ...

Running `du` against the full path adds the directory as a prefix to the output, eg:

```
$ du -sh /apps/newone/* | sort -hr 
12G     /apps/newone/lithium
11G     /apps/newone/sodium
160M    /apps/newone/soking
```

There are a few ways to get rid of the directory prefix depending on how the output is to be used going forward (eg, just sned to stdout? further processing in a `while` loop?).

One idea using `sed`:

```
$ du -sh /apps/newone/* | sort -hr | sed -E 's|\t/.*/|\t|'
12G     lithium
11G     sodium
160M    soking
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable extended regex support
- `s|<pattern1>|<pattern2|` - search for `<pattern1>` and if found then replace with `<pattern2>`
- `\t/.*/` - (`<pattern1>`) match a `<tab>` + `/` + `a variable number of characters` up to the last `\`
- `\t` - (`<pattern2>`) replace the match with a `<tab>` (ie, strip out the directory prefix)

No need for the `cd` commands, nor the redirection of `cd -` stdout to `/dev/null`, but we incur an extra sub-process call;

Comment: Great, thank you for the Help. I will try it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Both the commands are working. But with first method its 2X faster than using `sed` .

Answer (score 1):

`cd` to that directory in a subshell.

```
(cd /apps/newone ; du -sh * | sort -hr)
```